# Template tags cause "undefined is not a function" in programmatically-built directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating an AngularJS directive programmatically, but I'm noticing that when done this way, the template/scope compilation throws an error.

The following works fine when the directive exists within the html page already:

```
    dialogs.directive('workRequestDialog', function() {
        return {
            template: '<div>{{test}}</div>',
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                $scope.test = 'it worked';
            }]
        };
    });
```

It prints `<div>it worked</div>`

Creating and appending the element directly:

```
// Create DOM element
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute(userOptions.type, '');
div.setAttribute('class', 'panel modal ' + userOptions.type);

// Pass along configuration options, if any
var dialogScope = userOptions.options || {};

dialogScope.test = 'it works'; // even trying this fails

// Create directive
var dialog = angular.element(div);
var el = $compile(dialog)(dialogScope);
angular.element(document.body).append(dialog);
```

Causes this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at textInterpolateLinkFn (/assets/dist/libs/angular/angular.js:7016:23)
```

Comment: replace `angular.min.js` with the full `angular.js` and try again, it will identify which function `a` actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `dialogScope` doesn't seem to be a scope, especially when `userOptions.options` is undefined. Try to pass the current scope instead. If you don't have any scope available where this code is written, then it is not at the right place.

Comment: It shouldn't work there anyway. The $scope should be properly coming from the directive's controller - which it does *except* when created dynamically.

Comment: *Coming from the directive's controller*? It is not true, especially since some directives have no controller. A directive always has a parent scope, unless it has an isolated scope, which you can programatically create using `scope.$new(true)` (you should at least have access to `$rootScope`).

Comment: I mean in this scenario. Some values, due to organizational reasons, are defined in the controller for that directive. I can change it around, but the point is that every time this directive compiles, the scope always appears to have the right values. However, when compiled dynamically, it throws the error even though I see the same values on the scope. I've updated the answer with the correct angular trace

Comment: However, using $rootScope.$new(), appears solves the issue even though the values are still set in the controller

Comment: That is because the "non-dynamic" directive inherits from its parent scope (this is the default behavior), so its scope has access to all of the controller parent scope properties. If you want to do the same programatically, you need to link this parent scope to the compiled template, which is done by `$compile(dialog)(dialogScope)`. Here, `dialogScope` *need* to be the parent scope, or a scope at least. Using `$rootScope.$new` creates a scope that inheritates from the root one, however the directive won't inheritate from the properties of the parent controller.